# Create User Control and register in Asp.Net MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, user-controls, wrapper

I am creating reusable user controls in Asp.Net MVC 3 which will be used in different MVC project.
I know We can create Helper in MVC. but i want to go with Partial view. As we can create usercontrol library in Asp.Net and use it across all application. I want to do the same thing in MVC 3.

I found below article which is neatly explain. I tried to implement it , but it looks to be outdated as

> PrecompiledMvcEngine  is not found in nuget.

can anybody explains me how to do it in MVC3.

[Reusable UI Controls](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_ReusableUI.html)
I also used [Razor Generator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) but it will only create my view code in class.
what about the controller in that case.
Also how to refer other assembly view in current application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I think this is a more preferred and more current solution that uses built in functionality of MVC Areas that will save a lot of hassle in the future,

http://nileshhirapra.blogspot.com/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-pluggable-application.html

I think this is prefered because you can use

```
@Html.ActionLink("SomeAction", "SomeController", new {area = "SomePluginArea"})
```

Register Custom routes in your plugins using the AreaRegistration

**OLD ANSWER**

This is an old article but the same principle still applies I think this is what you want to achieve right?

http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins/

Code sample:

http://www.wynia.org/download/aspnetmvc-plugin-poc/POC.MVCPluginDemo.zip